# API Route Not Showing in route:list

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-5.7

I made Route in my routes->api, but when I do `php artisan route:list`, it shows me all routes except this route:

```html
Route::apiResources([
    'vh-invoice' => 'API\VhInvoiceController'
]);
```

Even when I remove some routes its shows me the same route:list, like I, removed these routes below, but in route:list it shows me the removed routes also, as you can see in the image below.

```html
Route::get('findVTI', 'API\TicketInvoiceController@searchVTI');
Route::get('selectVTI', 'API\TicketInvoiceController@selectVTI');
```

[image]

Comment: You may have your routes cached and need to clear the cache. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#route-caching

Comment: also did that but same....

Comment: @bradforbes yeah it's done i forgot to do `route:cache`

Comment: raise that as an answer please

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You may have your routes cached and need to clear the cache. You can run `php artisan route:cache` to refresh the cache.

Comment: This was my problem. For some reason, my routes were suddenly cached and Laravel didn't recognize a new route I added. Weird.